# Populating the first element in a group in another column

Tags: python-polars

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

`group_dict = {'doc_7': 1, 'doc_8': 2, 'doc_9': 2, 'doc_10': 2, 'doc_11': 5, 'doc_12': 1}`

I'm converting it to a dataframe as follows:

`doc_group_df = pl.from_records(list(group_dict.items()), orient='row', schema=['doc', 'group'])`

resulting in a dataframe that looks like this:

```
shape: (6, 2)
┌────────┬───────┐
│ doc    ┆ group │
│ ---    ┆ ---   │
│ str    ┆ i64   │
╞════════╪═══════╡
│ doc_7  ┆ 1     │
│ doc_8  ┆ 2     │
│ doc_9  ┆ 2     │
│ doc_10 ┆ 2     │
│ doc_11 ┆ 5     │
│ doc_12 ┆ 1     │
└────────┴───────┘
```

Now I need to add another column to this dataframe based on the doc ids in the first column and the group in the second column:

```
shape: (6, 3)
┌────────┬───────┬──────────────┐
│ doc    ┆ group ┆ original_doc │
│ ---    ┆ ---   ┆ ---          │
│ str    ┆ i64   ┆ str          │
╞════════╪═══════╪══════════════╡
│ doc_7  ┆ 1     ┆              │
│ doc_8  ┆ 2     ┆              │
│ doc_9  ┆ 2     ┆ doc_8        │
│ doc_10 ┆ 2     ┆ doc_8        │
│ doc_11 ┆ 5     ┆              │
│ doc_12 ┆ 1     ┆ doc_7        │
└────────┴───────┴──────────────┘
```

This is what I am doing to achieve this:

```
def original_doc(row):
    original_doc = sorted(doc_group_df.filter(pl.col('group')==row['group'])['doc'].to_list())[0]
    return original_doc if original_doc != row['doc'] else ''

doc_group_df.with_columns(pl.struct(pl.col('*')).apply(original_doc).alias('original_doc'))
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use a [`when`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.when.html#polars.when) expression for the if/else, and the column in question would be the `first` of each `doc` [`over`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.over.html#polars.Expr.over) the `group`:

```py
over_expr = pl.col('doc').first().over('group')

doc_group_df.with_columns(
    original_doc=pl.when(over_expr == pl.col('doc'))
    .then('')
    .otherwise(over_expr)
)
```

```py
shape: (6, 3)
┌────────┬───────┬──────────────┐
│ doc    ┆ group ┆ original_doc │
│ ---    ┆ ---   ┆ ---          │
│ str    ┆ i64   ┆ str          │
╞════════╪═══════╪══════════════╡
│ doc_7  ┆ 1     ┆              │
│ doc_8  ┆ 2     ┆              │
│ doc_9  ┆ 2     ┆ doc_8        │
│ doc_10 ┆ 2     ┆ doc_8        │
│ doc_11 ┆ 5     ┆              │
│ doc_12 ┆ 1     ┆ doc_7        │
└────────┴───────┴──────────────┘
```

This is a better way because it avoids using `apply` and a user-defined function, which is slow. This is fully parallelizable within the Rust backbone of Polars.

I believe Polars is smart enough to only evaluate `over_expr` once, you could try [`cache`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.cache.html#polars.Expr.cache) if you find it slow in any way (really shouldn't be though).

Comment: Awesome! I knew there had to be a way to not use `apply`! thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with two `with_columns` that way it only has to do the aggregation once.

```
(
    doc_group_df
        .with_columns(original_doc=pl.col('doc').first().over('group'))
        .with_columns(original_doc=pl.when(pl.col('original_doc')!=pl.col('doc'))
                                        .then(pl.col('original_doc')))
    )
```

If you prefer an actual empty string instead of a null then you can add an `otherwise`

```
(
    doc_group_df
        .with_columns(original_doc=pl.col('doc').first().over('group'))
        .with_columns(original_doc=pl.when(pl.col('original_doc')!=pl.col('doc'))
                                        .then(pl.col('original_doc'))
                                        .otherwise(pl.lit('')))
    )
```